# Search Engine Access to Google Drive Files

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-drive-api, web-crawler, search-engine

I found a public google drive, which contains many subfolders. What I'm trying to do is go through the google drive link and get the link to all the subfolders. I've checked Google Drive API and PyDrive, which is a wrapper library for Google Drive API, but both seem to only help out with personal Google Drive folders, not public ones. I've been stuck with this issue for a few days now, so I'm not sure where to head. I can scrape the Google Drive folder but I don't know if that's the most optimum way out. I've also thought of making strings of the url to each of the drive files and then working with that, but if the drive gets updated in the future, then I'd have to go back and see what other new files were added, and that's just not good practice. If anyone can put me on the right track, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: the API is the same for public as it is for private. The only difference is that for public files you don´t need to use OAuth/Access Token. Instead you only need an API_KEY

Comment: @pinoyyid can you link me to an example of that?

Comment: @KhalilHijazi the link to documentation is the same. You just authorize your client differently, because you don't have to do the OAuth dance - you just need your API key.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be done by creating an [OAuth2 Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account):

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth" refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.)

Even though you are dealing with a public Google Drive, I believe that you need to be authenticated to search it via Google's API.  To do this, you would use the service account to authenticate with the Google API.  An example (via the NodeJS client):

```js
'use strict';
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const FOLDER_ID = '1Mp_a-OyGGlk5tGkezYK41iZ2qybnrPzp';
const KEY_FILE = './my-iam-service-account-key.json'

const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: KEY_FILE,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
    })
});

drive.files.list({
    q: `'${FOLDER_ID}' in parents`,
})
    .then(({ data: { files, nextPageToken } }) => {
        if (nextPageToken) console.log("More to get", nextPageToken);
        return files;
    })
    .catch((res) => res.data)
    .then(console.log);
```